# OpenCV- Trackbar wont appear- window wont resize

Tags: opencv, python

Here's my code, the window doesnt seem to resize or show any of the trackbars. This just shows a blank window.

```
import cv2

def empty(a):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")
cv2.resizeWindow("Trackbars",640,300)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","Trackbars",0,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Max","Trackbars",179,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Min","Trackbars",0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Max","Trackbars",255,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Min","Trackbars",0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Max","Trackbars",255,255,empty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [namedWindow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b) API in Python:

```
Python:
    None = cv.namedWindow( winname[, flags] )
```

You should pass [`cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3) as a flag argument, It enables you to resize the window.

Just a reminder, you won't see the window without the loop, Because it will exit immediately after window has been created. I will suggest you add the loop like [`waitKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) in the end of the code.

Here is the modified code for demonstration:

```
import cv2

def empty(a):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Trackbars",640,300)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","Trackbars",0,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Max","Trackbars",179,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Min","Trackbars",0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Max","Trackbars",255,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Min","Trackbars",0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Max","Trackbars",255,255,empty)

ch = None
while ch != 27:
    ch = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Turns out it was the position of the cv2.waitKey(0) relative to where I had it in my code that caused the issue. Thanks for the help!